# Java Spring 3 REST Service Authentication

Tags: spring-3

I have REST web service using Spring 3. Here client is HTML. How can i implement the Username and Password authentication.

HTML client sends the Username and Password in header.

How can i get that header in one place and authenticate the user in Spring REST service.